# Kendo Grid page number input firing form submit

Tags: input, grid, kendo-ui, paging

We have some search related filter controls(textbox, dropdowns etc) on a form along with Search button which is a SUBMIT button for that form. Below to this we have a Kendo grid with paging enabled.

Problem: When we enter a page number(say 5 out of 100) and hit enter it is going back to page 1 because when we press enter, it is taking form submit and refreshing the form instead of navigating to 5th page

Help me to resolve this..

Comment: Please show us that what have you tried ?

Comment: I think he means when he presses enter the page refreshes and grid loses the page which grid was in before refresh. Solutions: 1. You can make your button ajax so clicking button should not refresh the page. 2.You can send current page number of grid when the button pressed and set the grid default page to the page. 3...

Answer (score 0):

Got it, took the grid out of form tag so that it works independently